# Does Gzip only compress the files, or also decrease the HTTP requests?

Tags: apache, http, gzip, bandwidth

I have the following webpage (example page, as the original is very large),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/layout.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="_js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="_js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="_js/chat.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am serving this page without compressing it with gzip or other utilities. 
I know that gzip increases cpu usage for decreasing the bandwidth consumption, that's not the issue, but I want to know about one thing before using it,

In my example code above, the page after loading the initial DOM sends 5 http requests to the server (2 for CSS files and 3 for javascript files).

If I gzip the same page, would it only compress (and decrease) the size of the html file and CSS files and JavaScript files, or does it also combine them all before serving, thus decreasing the http requests ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't combine requests, you need to do that yourself. It only compresses what gets sent over.

Comment: Would you please give me some link, which explains what you said ?